# Failing in starting a new activity(android)

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to start a new activity but my app stop.
If the if condition is true then the register activity is executed and work but if false then the track activity stop my app
Here is the code:

```
if(condition)
{
    Intent register = new Intent(HomeActivity.this, Register.class);
    HomeActivity.this.startActivity(register);
}
else
{
    Intent login = new Intent(HomeActivity.this, Track.class);
    HomeActivity.this.startActivity(login);
}
```

Maybe it's something with my Track class?

logcat:

```
    12-21 15:46:16.265: D/AndroidRuntime(540): Shutting down VM
12-21 15:46:16.265: W/dalvikvm(540): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40c711f8)
12-21 15:46:16.265: E/AndroidRuntime(540): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-21 15:46:16.265: E/AndroidRuntime(540): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.android.location/com.example.android.location.HomeActivity}: android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {com.example.android.location/com.example.android.location.Track}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?
12-21 15:46:16.265: E/AndroidRuntime(540):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1970)
12-21 15:46:16.265: E/AndroidRuntime(540):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1995)
12-21 15:46:16.265: E/AndroidRuntime(540):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:128)
12-21 15:46:16.265: E/AndroidRuntime(540):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1161)
12-21 15:46:16.265: E/AndroidRuntime(540):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
12-21 15:46:16.265: E/AndroidRuntime(540):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
12-21 15:46:16.265: E/AndroidRuntime(540):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4514)
12-21 15:46:16.265: E/AndroidRuntime(540):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-21 15:46:16.265: E/AndroidRuntime(540):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
12-21 15:46:16.265: E/AndroidRuntime(540):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:993)
12-21 15:46:16.265: E/AndroidRuntime(540):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:760)
12-21 15:46:16.265: E/AndroidRuntime(540):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
12-21 15:46:16.265: E/AndroidRuntime(540): Caused by: android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {com.example.android.location/com.example.android.location.Track}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?
12-21 15:46:16.265: E/AndroidRuntime(540):  at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1512)
12-21 15:46:16.265: E/AndroidRuntime(540):  at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1388)
12-21 15:46:16.265: E/AndroidRuntime(540):  at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3281)
12-21 15:46:16.265: E/AndroidRuntime(540):  at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:3388)
12-21 15:46:16.265: E/AndroidRuntime(540):  at com.example.android.location.HomeActivity.onCreate(HomeActivity.java:44)
12-21 15:46:16.265: E/AndroidRuntime(540):  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4562)
12-21 15:46:16.265: E/AndroidRuntime(540):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1053)
12-21 15:46:16.265: E/AndroidRuntime(540):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1934)
12-21 15:46:16.265: E/AndroidRuntime(540):  ... 11 more
```

Comment: Are you getting errors in your `LogCat` that you can share with us?

Comment: Please provide a stack trace

Comment: please add some logcat lines

Comment: Definitely logcat and maybe at least the `onCreate()' of 'Track` class

Comment: Press in Eclipse: Window > Show View > Other. Then under Android, Choose LogCat. Run the application again and you will see red lines when this happens. Copy the red lines and paste them here

Comment: I added the logcat lines

Comment: It can't find `Track.class` in your manifest: `have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?`

Comment: From the log cat it looks as if it hasn't been declared in the manifest file. Could you add the manifest to your post as well

Comment: I changed my class name and didn't updated the manifest. Thank you guys!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it can be because of missing declarqation of calla in manifest add below line to manifest

```
 <activity android:name=".Track">
     <intent-filter>
          <action android:name="android.intent.action.ACTIVITY" />
     </intent-filter>
  </activity>
```

[ADDITION 1]

if you look at log you will see

> Unable to find explicit activity class
>   {com.example.android.location/com.example.android.location.Track};
>   have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?

Comment: It should be "Track" and not "Register"

Answer (score 2):

```
<activity android:name=".Track" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to declare your Activity in your manifest.xml file...maybe this could be the reason

Answer (score 0):

Your Track class is not declared in your Manifest as your logcat showing. Try to add that Track class in your manifest.

```
     <activity
        android:name=".Track"
        android:label="@string/app_name">
    </activity>
```